# Why did Rita Vrataski remove Cage's armour suit's battery the first time he got shot?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

The first time Cage saves Rita, he gets shot in the chest. At that time, Rita takes away the battery from his Armour suit. Why did she do that? At that point of time, she didn't knew Cage has the ability to control time.

All she cares is about winning the war. He was gonna die anyway, so she could have left him there to die with the battery.

Later in the movie, she tells him if he gets injured in battlefield, make sure to die there. Otherwise, he will be taken to the hospital and will be injected with someone's blood and lose the ability to control time. It matters only if he has the ability to control time. That's how she lost it.

So, doesn't taking away the battery mean she knew he had the ability to control time? If not, why did she care about him? If he dies in the field, or gets injured and  taken to a hospital and injected with someone else's blood it's his fault. She doesn't even know him.

What's the reason for such an act?

Comment: This question can be rephrased to "The first time Cage saves Rita, he gets shot in the chest. At that time, Rita takes away the battery from his Armour suit. Why did she do that?" Everything else is superfluous.

Comment: @BobbyAlexander Well, I'd prefer a middle ground between the currently quite heavy elaboration and your one-liner without any context. Part of the question is reasoning why that seemed unusual to the OP and thus required to give the question the necessary substance.

Comment: I don't think the question is superfluous. After watching a movie, we all try to connect the dots.That's when doubts arise. I needed to make clear why I felt so. So explanation does matter. @Bobby Alexander

Comment: I rephrased it to make it more concise, there were a few unnecessary points being repeated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The suits in the movie are battery powered. Rita knew Cage was going to die so he wouldn't need it. So she just took it for herself (in case she runs out of power).

Edit:

Not an official source but I was able to find [this article](http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/06/science-on-the-edge-of-tomorrow/) on TechCrunch.

> Battery life was also a critical concern. Liman suggested that in the
>   movie, world battery technology has taken a major step forward to
>   enable these battle suits to operate without being plugged in, but “as
>   futuristic as “Edge of Tomorrow” is, it’s not unintentional that Emily
>   Blunt steals Tom Cruise’s battery the first time they meet on the
>   battlefield; we’re always going to be looking at our battery meter and
>   wishing we had more juice.

Comment: That's the only possibility. That explains her behavior.

Comment: Great, that quote makes this already reasonable answer into a very good and definite one. Sure +1.

Comment: if battery was the concern, she could carry additional battery as cruse does.

Comment: @Lokesh Sure, but what if that gets empty, too. They really seemed to have to get any juice they could out of those batteries and they're likely not giving you tens of those things. Really shows her efficiency in staying alive by taking everything she could get.

Comment: Was he carrying an extra battery?

Comment: No at that time, he wasn't carrying an extra battery. She took the only battery he had. That's why he asks her 'Did you just take my battery?' or something similar to that. @Bobby Alexander

Comment: @BeingJudas: That's what I thought. My comment was in response to Lokesh's comment.

Comment: Sorry...I didn't notice that. One extra battery= more time in the battlefield. @Bobby Alexander

Comment: Also, in the book, Rita explains to dying the Keiji that she is going to be with him till he dies and then take his batteries off him. She does this with all dead metal suits to keep herself going in the battle.